# How do I skip checking for my position

Tags: loops, for-loop

```
    for (int x = 0; x <= battleField.getCols(); x++){
                for (int y = 0; y <= battleField.getRows(); y++){

                    if ((battleField.get(x,y) == team) && ((x + y)
                            != battleField.get(row, col)))
                    {
                                .
                                .
                                .
                    }
               }
   }
```

battleField.get(row, col) will return my position on a grid now my question is that how do I skip my self from checking where my position is ? because when the for loop checks for x and y it goes through the whole grid. What do I have to do?

Comment: Why should X+Y be unique? for every (row, col) there would be a (col,row) which should give the same value. Can you elaborate battlefield.get(x,y) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
((x + y) != battleField.get(row, col))
```

I think you want

```
(x != row && y != col)
```

If you did want that first part you could just add this to the beginning of your inner for loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= battleField.getCols(); x++){
            for (int y = 0; y <= battleField.getRows(); y++){

                if(x == row && y == col) // This will check if the loop is looking at your position
                    continue; // This will go to the next step in the "y" for loop, essentially skipping the rest of the code in this block

                if ((battleField.get(x,y) == team) && ((x + y)
                        != battleField.get(row, col)))
                {
                            .
                            .
                            .
                }
           }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variables for your current position are named `current_x` and `current_y`, then you could do something like this inside your loop...

```
bool isMyPosition = (x == current_x) && (y == current_y);

if ( !isMyPosition 
    && (battleField.get(x,y) == team)
    && ((x + y) != battleField.get(row, col)))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: you are correct too but i just wanted a simpler solution to my problem  . thank you though

Answer (score 0):

if(Question.IsAbout(EscapingOnCheck))

Most languages have some kind of `continue` that can be used to escape a loop when a condition is met.

else

Save your current position in some variables, and add another nested loop (for debugging's sake) or add an && clause (for less code's sake)